# Laravel Message from API (Ajax)

Tags: ajax, laravel, message

I have a Laravel project and would like the API server to return a message (validation) that will be displayed in Laravel.

Laravel

```
<script>
    jQuery('#ajaxSubmit').click(function(e){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: $("#r").val(),
            data: {
                i:$("#i").val(),
                c:$("#c").val(),
                cn:$("#cn").val(),
                s:$("#s").val(),
                m:$("#m").val(),
          
            },
            success: function(response) {
                if($.isEmptyObject(response.error)){
                    location.reload();
                }else{
                    printErrorMsg(response.error);
                }
            }
        });
    });
    function printErrorMsg (msg) {
        $(".print-error-msg").find("ul").html('');
        $(".print-error-msg").css('display','block');
        $.each( msg, function( key, value ) {
            $(".print-error-msg").find("ul").append('<li>'+value+'</li>');
        });
    }
</script>
```

API Server

```
return response()->json(['error' => 'My Message']);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You haven't actually asked a question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe

```
response.error
```

must be

```
response.data.error
```